# How do I keep a column highlighted when hovering over it?

Tags: css, hover, dreamweaver, highlight, css-tables

I am in an Intro to Web class this semester and I go above all that I have to do so nothing has held me back from learning things that I would like to use.  I have a table set up with categories on the first row and the following rows are numbers, set up like a Jeopardy game.  When I roll over a column, I want the whole column to highlight, and so on with the following columns.  My problem is that when I hover over my column it highlights the column, but when I go down to each specific cell in that column, they gradually unhighlight.  I just want them to stay highlighted! I work in CSS, I have never used Jquery before and only a little Javascript, but I am willing to receive information for all. Just preferably CSS, if it is possible.

**CSS**

```
td:hover{
    background-color: 5a5b93;
}

td {
    position: relative;
}

td:hover::after {
    background-color: #563A81;
    content: '\00a0';
    height: 10000px;
    left: 0;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Go to jsfiddle.net and post some sample CSS and HTML so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way how this can be done with CSS. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zp5mr/1/) with jQuery.

### SNIPPET

```
var th = $("th, td");

th.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        n = $this.index() + 1;
    $this.hover(function() {
        var col = $("tr > td:nth-child(" + n + ")");
        col.addClass("hovered");
    });
});
```

### USAGE

jQuery is a Javascript library. This means it needs source code. The library itself needs to be loaded before you can execute a jQuery script because browsers don't "know" jQuery by default. You can do this by adding the script in the  of your document. Preferably **after** your style sheets (*`*.css`*) and **before** other *`<script>`*'s.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now that that's settled, we can add the code above to our document. Beware though! JavaScript can only call an element when it has already been loaded. What we want to do, then, is to execute our snippet when the whole document (and the elements we need) are loaded. We can do this, by putting the above code into a doc-ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var th = $("th, td");

    th.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            n = $this.index() + 1;
        $this.hover(function () {
            var col = $("tr > td:nth-child(" + n + ")");
            col.addClass("hovered");
        });
    });
});
```

Remeber to put this snippet in `<script>`-tags and **after** the jQuery library.

The ´head` of your document will look sort-of like this (in that order):

```
<head>
<!-- Bunch of meta tags -->
<link href="/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var th = $("th, td");

        th.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                n = $this.index() + 1;
            $this.hover(function () {
                var col = $("tr > td:nth-child(" + n + ")");
                col.addClass("hovered");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Am I supposed to add that to my code, or get rid of what I have posted up there ^^ and where would I put this code, in my HTML? I've never done jQuery so I am just a little unfamiliar with what to do with that.

Comment: Should I get rid of the code I originally had and put that in?

Comment: I tried putting it in, and it wasn't working.  I don't know. Wah, this is aggravating.  Haha.

Comment: @Leah No, you should NOT put the original code in. Try using your browser's dev tools (F12) and look at the `console`. Which errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think your gonna need some jquery... There is a good tutorial here on column highlighting http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/, Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dylanholmes222/XbKWA/) with a working example of the gist of the tut.

**HTML**

```
<table>  
<colgroup></colgroup>
<colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
<colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
<colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
<colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>   
<thead>
      <tr>
           <th></th>
           <th></th>
           <th></th>
           <th></th>
           <th></th>
       </tr>
    </thead>       
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
```

**CSS**

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { font: 14px Georgia, serif; }

#page-wrap { width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; }

table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
td, th { border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px; }

.slim { width: 88px; }
.hover { background-color: #eee; }
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

  $("table").delegate('td','mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
      $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
      $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).addClass("hover");
    } else {
      $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
      $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).removeClass("hover");
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: edited my answer: added some code from the tut and made a fiddle to play with the code.